# Техники построения механизма тарифных планов

Tags: биллинг, тарификация

Привет всем!

Кто нибудь сталкивался с созданием системы тарифных планов в своем продукте? Мне интересно знать, как сделать систему таким образом, чтобы она могла тарифицировать любые показатели)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут смотря что в конечном итоге Вам нужно:

**Пример**

Нужно тарифицировать клиента в зависимости от количества потребляемого ресурса. Есть три тарифных плана, которые зависят от количества употребляемых ресурсов. Мы должны высчитать "начальный" тариф (например):

```
if(res>0 and res<=10)
   // set tarif 1
elseif(res>10 and res<100)
   // set tarif 2
elseif(res>=100)
   // set tarif 3
```

У меня была одна конечная формула, которая высчитывала конечную суму, которую должен заплатить абонент,при условии что у нас еще были разные услуги, штрафы и бонусы(которые высчитывались другими формулами, методами ...).
Примерно так:

```
endSum = tarif + services + penalty - bonus
```

Если совсем заморачиваться то в админке можно сделать редактор формул для тарифов.

**UPD**

С генератором формул все куда запущенней :)

1) Должна быть таблица показателей и формул (billing_parameters сократим до BP)

> |id|name|type|note|

где *type* - это *static, interval* или *dynamic* и ведут на отдельные таблицы

**static**

```
|id_BP|name|param| 
a=10
```

**interval**

```
|id_BP|name|min|max|param| 
a=10 если попало в предел min-max
записей на один id_PB может быть несколько
```

**dynamic**

```
|id_BP|type|formula|
записей на один id_PB будет несколько
```

*type* - *element* или *formula*

*formula* - то что ввел пользователь в строковом виде

**Небольшая ремарка перед вторым пунктом**

По райтклику на инпут поле выскакивает меню выбора показателя:

```
Name - note
Bonus - Бонусы за попугаев
```

при выборе в формулу попадает `Name` и к нам в `list` для того что бы потом добавить все внесенные параметры в БД.

2) Я сразу перейду к самим формулам

В конечном итоге у нас будет несколько методов - для вычисления *интервалов* и собственно самой *формулы*.

Делаем словарь ключ:значение, для того что бы заносить в него посчитанные параметры.
В таблице **dynamic** у нас есть все простые элементы формулы, мы их считаем и заносим в словарь name:param, потом берем формулу и реплейсим в ней имена показателей на посчитаные показатели, у нас готовая математическая формула, **профит**

Comment: Здравствуйте! Вот как раз, редактор тарифов и интересует)

Comment: обновил ответ

Comment: Благодарю за инфу, буду изучать :]